# Store header data in URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-headers

We are building a shopping web site and need to display hundreds of products and their images. We don't have the product images, but a separate company's service does.

I was given access to this API service. `GET`ting a product image at endpoint `https://imageservice.com/api/v3/images/{product_UPC}` requires header `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`.

This returns a response with an array of applicable product image variants. Each image in the response array is at a URL like `https://imageservice.com/api/v3/asset/[hash]`. These hashed image URLs are one-time use and must be requested with the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` again to actually display the image.

This makes the request process to our own API for products difficult as we cannot seed our database with products and their respective image URLs. Instead, each time our shopping site requests products from our own database, we must request the images separately by product ID, loop through the products and match images to each.

**Additionally, their service is throttled to about 20 requests every 10 seconds** and we load 30-40 products in each paginated call. This will slow the display of products if we don't initially load the URLs into the database.

**Question**: We already have a paid license and API key to use this separate image API service, and I already have each product in our DB stored with its correct image URL. The problem is we need to pass the **header** `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` along with the URL without forming an entirely new AJAX request. How can this be done?

Comment: Would you not just simply make a request for each image with the header set?  What is the actual issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is we need to pass the header Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key along with the URL without forming an entirely new AJAX request. How can this be done?

If your question is how to query the image without making requests, then short answer is **no, you can’t**. Headers are made for security reasons. If the target service requires headers and not only URL parameters, then you’ll have to send a new request each time you want to retrieve an image, following each step they require.

I see only 2 solutions

**Look further into your API**

The API used by the company you retrieve images for may have some deeper options, to allow you more control over it. For example, a function to retrieve many images at once, in one single request.

Take a greater look at it, it might be **your best solution**.

**Not using request**

If neither of above proposals fits your desire, then you have no choice but **storing images on your own**. You deal with an external API, which seem to be private. Thus, you are limited by the work of your partner company, which is totally normal and expected. They may have put those limitations for a good reason, and overpassing them can lead to unsecure behaviors.

If you want maximum control, then you need to handle the most of it by yourself. If you are tied to your partner company work, then you have to see with them what permission they can give you and how you can maximize profits from their work.

**EDIT**

You can also format your requests, using AJAx or alternatives, such as [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). Take a greater look at this one. This will, at least, avoid you setting all request parameters on each call.